# Distribution of rank differences for a paired dataset

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, distributions, statistical-significance, ranks

I guess I have a rather simple question but I couldn't find the answer in previous posts. I have a paired dataset in which the same objects are ranked under two different conditions, here A and B:

```
> data
      rankA  rankB
obj1  3      4
obj2  2      2
obj3  5      1
obj4  6      5
obj5  1      3
obj6  4      6
```

I want to know what are the objects that are showing the most significant changes between the two conditions, so to begin with I calculate a rank difference statistics, here "delta":

```
> data
      rankA  rankB  delta
obj1  3      4      -1
obj2  2      2      0
obj3  5      1      4
obj4  6      5      1
obj5  1      3      -2
obj6  4      6      -2
```

Now my question is what is the distribution of this delta statistics if the ranks were generated randomly? As I said my intention is to find objects that show the most significant difference between two conditions, I want to have this randomly generated delta distribution for my null hypothesis so for each specific object I can estimate what is the likelihood that I see a delta value that extreme.

My first guess was that the distribution should be normal but when I randomly simulated dummy datasets it doesn't look normal at all and is more like a sharp smooth triangle, see here for 1 million random ranks:

```
#set.seed(1)
list1 <- sample(1:1000000, 1000000, replace = FALSE)

#set.seed(2)
list2 <- sample(1:1000000, 1000000, replace = FALSE)

delta <- list2 - list1

hist(delta, breaks = 200)
```

[image]

Any idea on what is this distribution and how I can calculate my p-values? Thanks!

*NOTE* that I'm not using wilkoxon or signed tests as I'm not interested in comparing whether the two ranked lists are from the same population or not, I'm interested in the individual objects ranked, but I'm open to any suggestion or other methods that I could use instead! Thank you!

Comment: If the two ranks columns are uniformly distributed then their difference will be a triangular distribution.

Comment: While a given rank might be discrete uniform, the whole collection of ranks are not independent, even if the original sample values were. If there are no ties, each (unsigned) rank appears once in each sample.

Comment: Would it help to think of the distribution as where the say "7"s go on a Sudoku game, or how 8 non-attacking rooks can be placed on a chess board? Your deltas are the distance (horizontal or vertical) from the diagonal.

Comment: @Glen_b tnx, I'm not quite sure I can get your point, does it mean the distribution is not gonna be triangular?

Comment: @user2974951 thanks. So with this triangular distribution do you think it makes sense for me to estimate p-values for my delta? based on distribution parameters from this post for example?

Comment: With these paired values (two ranks on each object), the triangular marginal distribution would apply if the two sets of ranks were such that they were no more alike than if they had been unpaired (i.e. as if the ranks were assigned each time as if the two sets of rankings had nothing to do with each other at all). This would correspond to a most strange null hypothesis but was not the thing I was concerned about. Rather it was the drawing a set of those rank differences as if they would be independent of each other (per your diagram) and then immediately asking a question about p-values...ctd

Comment: ctd... -- now there's a potential trap to avoid, though it depends on the precise hypothesis you attempt to test (and so how you should generate a p-value). I was attempting to warn you not to treat the collection of rank differences as if they were independent if you were computing a collective p-value for them (as it seemed you might if you did  a single overall test).

Answer (score 1):

You write

> I want to know what are the objects that are showing the most
> significant changes between the two conditions

I think "significant" is misused here. To establish significance, you need a hypothesis. If you mean "largest" then you can just look at delta. You then look at a distribution of differences of ranks (1 million ranks!) and ask about it. But that distribution could be used to test the significance of your own whole distribution against that distribution. E.g. if your ranks were more likely to be close to 0, then the average delta would be lower.

But you say you don't want that. So, just use delta.

Comment: Thank you Peter! This was my first question here so my apologies for not being clear. I understand your point about the largest delta and I already have those values, but what I miss here is how confident I can be about those big delta values not being a mere chance, or in other words how far down the list of these biggest delta values I can go to shortlist objects. That is why I wanted to do hypothesis testing with delta distributions from random ranks, so I can use find critical values for the delta at for example p=0.05. Is there a more statistically sound way for me to estimate that? Tnx!

Comment: The hypothesis test would be something like "is my distribution of ranks random?" or, more precisely "is the mean delta in my distribution smaller than the mean delta between two uniform distributions".

It will be. It sort of has to be, unless your pairing really stinks.

You should use a substantive reason to decide on a delta that is "too big".